# Dotnet CLI build Code with different code and output directory

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd, msbuild, dotnet-cli

I am trying to build my application with dotnet cli, the applications build successfully but the output directory is never updated. I already have similar thing done in  msbuild but due to C#7 I have to switch to DotNet CLI

1. Is there a way to build C# 7 application in msbuild
2. How to convert msbuild command to dotnet cli command

MSBuild Command:

```
msbuild C:\abc\abc.sln -maxcpucount /p:OutputPath=C:\xyz\xyz_publish
```

DotNet CLI Command:

```
dotnet build C:\abc\abc.sln -o C:\xyz\xyz_publish
```

also tried:

```
dotnet publish C:\abc\abc.sln -c Debug -o C:\xyz\xyz_publish
```

Comment: What happens when you delete all files in the output directory and build the project?

Comment: @MindSwipe it builds the project only `.dll` are generated whereas `_PublishedWebsites` is not created

Comment: I can't help you further, I can only link [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2018/03/13/where-is-my-_publishedwebsites-folder/) msdn blog entry as I have no experience with asp.net